# Running Powershell in .NET solution post-build in a cross-platform way

Tags: .net, visual-studio, powershell, .net-core

If I want to run a Powershell script after build in Visual Studio, I can do it like this in the post build event in the project properties:

```
"C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -file $(SolutionDir)Powershell\Post-Build.ps1
```

This is included in the project file, and respected by `dotnet build`, so it also works on the command line.

The path of the Powershell binary seems to be guaranteed on all Windows systems that includes Powershell, so the absolute path of PS is not an issue.

This is all great. But how would I rewrite the reference to the `powershell` bin so it works cross platform? Is there a way to resolve the path of the PS binary, utilizing PS Core (`pwsh`) on non-Windows platforms?

Comment: PowerShell Core and PowerShell are mostly, but not exactly fully compatible yet, so using one or the other seems sub-optimal anyway. How about simply mandating that PowerShell Core is installed and in the path? This is doable on Windows as well, and then you could simply use `pwsh` universally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As close as they may be, PowerShell Core is not a 1:1 match for functionality with Windows PowerShell. PowerShell Core is PowerShell 6+ while Windows PowerShell is 5.1 and earlier. If you want a cross platform solution, the correct answer here is to go with PowerShell Core as your standard PowerShell version, and make sure that it's installed as a dependency on both your Windows and Linux nodes.

Comment: And if I were to use Powershell Core, would you recommend the solution given by Jeroen Mostert in the comments? Require `pwsh` to be in the path?

Comment: On Windows, `pwsh` should already be on the PATH once installed. On Linux, the entrypoint will typically go somewhere already on the PATH. In either case, you should make sure that `pwsh` is on the PATH, and add it if it is not.